# Library/tools in PHP for wiki-style diff and history

Tags: php, diff, markup

## Background

I'm looking to create a wiki-style website.
First I took a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software
Wanting to use PHP and being sceptic about using plain file storage the choice was lijited down to three alternatives:

- Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware
- PhpWiki
- MediaWiki

Correct me if I'm wrong but all of these felt very heavyweight and pretty much overkill for a rather small project.

## The question

My idea was then to use some kind of existing libraries and/or tools for the history, diff and markup parts but implementing the rest myself.

Do you know of any (good) libraries and/or tools like these?

Comment: I built a wiki on top of Text_Diff: http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/redirected .  For markup, investigate WYSIWYG editor compatibility -- there are a lot of markup libs that don't have available accompanying WYSIWYG editors.  And finally, ask yourself: do you really need to create yet another wiki platform when there are already dozens to choose from?  What will yours do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an existing library like `Markdown` for marking up wiki text. Extend it if you have to. A diff algorithm for a wiki can be as trivial as you want it to be. First result on google for `php diff` showed an extremely simple algorithm that will probably get you started in the right direction.

[PHP Diff Algorithm](https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php)

[PHP Markdown](https://github.com/wolfie/php-markdown)

Also don't forget about Github! There are all kinds of wiki projects written in PHP on there. [Like this one!](https://github.com/isofarro/php5-markdown-wiki)

Comment: The second link is down